# Does a Searing Smite-charged weapon count as magical, or just do extra damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

More specifically, consider the [Gray Ooze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gray-ooze)'s ability to...

> ***Corrode Metal.*** Any nonmagical weapon made of metal that hits the ooze
>   corrodes. After dealing damage, the weapon takes a permanent and
>   cumulative -1 penalty to damage rolls.

If my Forge cleric casts [*searing smite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/searing-smite) on his otherwise normal warhammer and I land a blow, is my hammer still gonna get jacked up?

Answer (score 15):

## The warhammer will take the corrosive damage

> #### *Searing Smite*
>
> *The next time you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack during the spell's duration, your weapon flares with white-hot intensity, and the attack deals and extra 1d6 fire damage to the target and causes the target to ignite in flames.*—**PHB, page 274**

In 5th edition, [Spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107637/42386). At no point does Searing Smite say something to the effect of "this spell makes your weapon magical" or "this spell makes your weapon immune to damage" or any other similar effect. Using Searing Smite would not affect a weapon's vulnerability to Gray Ooze's feature, or other similar features.